# How to select last row inserted

Tags: c#, sql

I inserted values into an SQL table that has an auto increment primary key and I want to get the Pk value that the last insert has it. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MYSQL?

Comment: use MAX(columnname) in your sql query...

Comment: You can order by the key with DESC and take the first row

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@LastInsertedId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

you should use this after insert query

```
insert into table(ColumnName)values("name")
@LastInsertedId=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the PK when you insert values you can use this code:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column2,column3,column4)
OUTPUT Inserterd.column1
VALUES (value1,value2,value3)
```

in above code `column1` is the PK that is auto increment you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you first add a column in your named Updatedate (datetime), then you can just write the query like below :

```
Select top 1 * 
From TableName 
Order By Updatedate desc
```

Comment: This is **NOT** going to work in a system with even just medium load of concurrent users - by the time your code gets to the point to select the `TOP 1` row, one or several **more** rows could have been inserted by other users of the system. This is **NOT RELIABLE** and thus **NOT RECOMMENDED!**